# Highcharts error "cannot read property of undefined"

Tags: javascript, angularjs, highcharts

I'm creating a chart using Highcharts (and getting the data from a JSON file). However, I'm getting `TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined`.

I have the following code:

```
myData.get(function (data) {
      $scope.loadData = data;
    });


$('#container').highcharts({

    xAxis: {
        type: 'datetime'
    },

    series: [{
        name: 'Temperature',
        data: $scope.loadData.map(function(d) {
          return [d.timestamp, d.actual];
        })
    }, {
        name: 'Range',
        data: $scope.loadData.map(function(d) {
          return [d.timestamp, d.min, d.max];
        }),
        type: 'arearange'
    }]
});
```

I've also created a [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/asbFPbHhiCx7PAyNs8kt?p=preview).

Any tips on what I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: $scope.loadData is supposed to be an array, so if you just add $scope.loadData = []; on top of your controller, at least you won't have this error again. http://plnkr.co/edit/xcKPn8zbk6hpmjiQ7ZhW?p=preview

Comment: true but it's still not printing the data :/

Answer (score 3):

So I changed your Plunkr to a working example: http://plnkr.co/edit/Q4z6NdVtp3TRMKgmH5tc?p=preview

First of all, in your data.json you have **timestamps** added as **strings**. Highchart does not accept that.

I changed the factory to get JSON data via $http

```
.factory('myData', function($http) { 
    return {
     getData : function () {
       var data = [];
      data = $http.get('data.json');
      return data;
     }
  }
})
```

In the callback of getData I build the chart:

```
myData.getData().then(function(response) { 
    $scope.loadData = response.data;

    $('#container').highcharts({

        xAxis: {
            type: 'datetime'
        },

        series: [{
            name: 'Temperature',
            data: [$scope.loadData.timestamp, $scope.loadData.actual]
        }, 
        {
            name: 'Range',
            data: [$scope.loadData.timestamp, $scope.loadData.min, $scope.loadData.max],
            type: 'arearange'
        }]
    });
  });
```

Comment: I see. Thanks for the example. The data isn't loading properly, though, but I'll dig into it. Tks. :)

Comment: Probably because I added random timestaps in your data.json. ;-)

Comment: I don't think so, I changed the timestamps to actual ones but it's still not displaying correctly.

Comment: There are no errors but it's displaying only two points and wrong numbers (and it's not displaying the range series).

Comment: Looks like your data points are not proportional, because when we refer to particular points, then ranges are printed properly: http://plnkr.co/edit/slNAwadFzdOMmKkgoUjq?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

this is asynchronous call :

```
myData.get(function (data) {
    console.log("myData.Get");
    $scope.loadData = data;
});
```

So `$('#container').highcharts({...` will run before the data is set `$scope.loadData = data;`

you have to move the code inside the callback of `myData`

```
myData.get(function (data) {
    $scope.loadData = data;

        $('#container').highcharts({
            xAxis: {
                type: 'datetime'
            },

            series: [{
                name: 'Temperature',
                data: $scope.loadData.map(function(d) {
                  return [d.timestamp, d.actual];
                })
            }, {
                name: 'Range',
                data: $scope.loadData.map(function(d) {
                  return [d.timestamp, d.min, d.max];
                }),
                type: 'arearange'
            }]
        });

});
```

Comment: tks, i'll have a look into it.